# Why hasn't Reed Richards cured Alicia Masters of her blindness?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four

Reed offered himself to revert The Thing's condition plenty of times, to which he refused.

What about Alicia's blindness?

Did he offer as well and she refused it?

Or is it something beyond their capability?

Comment: Her sight has been restored (and lost again) on a bunch of occasions. It's generally considered to be beyond the capability of the Fantastic Four to restore it without the application of radioactive chemicals (obvs) from the future or from alien worlds.

Comment: This is a standard application of the trope named, literally, Reed Richards is Useless. There are many other things that cannot happen (permanently) in Marvel comics because it is supposed to be close to the real world, so you cannot have the capability to enable vision with a snap of the fingers when this is still years out in real life (current technology is blurry and grayscale). An obvious explanation would be that Alicia simply is not interested in being sighted, but I do not know if this idea has occurred to the writers.

Comment: @Adamant also curing the blindness means you lose part of her characterization. For long running series that likes the status quo changing a core character trait like that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reed and the Fantastic Four have made at least one effort to restore her sight, in [*Fantastic Four Vol.1 #19*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_19)

---

The loss of her eyesight (as a result of a chemical explosion) is evidently not curable by any means at Reed's disposal. They try to locate a radioactive herb with restorative properties from the past.

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't make it into the future.

[image]

Comment: Haha, silly Reed. _Everything_ has "radio-active properties"!

Comment: Funny... they could go to the past, but couldn't bring the radioactive herb to the future. Why not bring Alicia to the past, cure her there, and then return?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Your logic and common sense have no place in this discussion.